# Store Image String on Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, uitextview

Im able to display my image and text within the textview however when sending to firestore only the text is saved not the string image

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey :Any]) {

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let image = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
        // create an NSMutableAttributedString that we'll append everything to
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = image



        //calculate new size.  (-20 because I want to have a litle space on the right of picture)
        let newImageWidth = (textField.bounds.size.width - 20 )
        let scale = newImageWidth/image.size.width
        let newImageHeight = image.size.height * scale
        //resize this
        attachment.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: newImageHeight)
       // let newPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument

        let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
        textField.textStorage.insert(attrStringWithImage, at: textField.selectedRange.location)

}


   let postRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").document()
                postRef.setData(["Description": self.textField.text!], merge: true)
```

Comment: You are trying to save an image in a field that will only take a string in Firestore. You cannot do that. Firestore doesn’t know what attributedString is. It only knows string. I suggest you go through a few tutorials of how to save text and images of a post in firestore. There are plenty online.

Comment: but I'm using a text view and the only way to add images in a text view is by converting that image to a string

Comment: It is not a string. It is an attachment for the attibutedString. At no point it is coded or decoded back and forth. What you can do is save the actual image to Firebase, I am saying Firebase, not firestore, because you will save it as an actual image in storage, this image will have a download url which you can store in firestore. When you need to retrieve it, just get it from the download url and add it back to your textView as an attachment.